# latexmkrc config file checking for errors (cleaning & synctex.gz)

Tags: latexmk

Cleaning process has no effect & main.`synctex.gz` is not generated.
I'm trying to clean the folder after compilation, and also I want to have a `synctex.gz` file to jump from .pdf to the source. It seems that is not generated.

- Using: lualatex
- OS: Windows 10
- Perl: installed

```pl
# This shows how to use lualatex (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX)
# with latexmk.  
#
#   WARNING: The method shown here is suitable only for ver. 4.51 and
#            later of latexmk, not for earlier versions.
#
#
@default_files = ("*.tex");
$recorder = 1;
$show_time = 1;
$pdf_mode = 4;
$biber = 'biber %O %S';
$latex = "pdflua -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -synctex=1 %O %S";
push @generated_exts, 'synctex.gz';
$pdf_previewer = 'start "D:\PortableApp\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %O %S';
$makeindex = "makeindex %O -o %D %S";
$cleanup_mode = 2;
$clean_ext = " %R-mod.blg %R-mod.aux %R-mod.bbl";

add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'run_makeglossaries');

sub run_makeglossaries {
  if ( $silent ) {
    system "makeglossaries -q '$_[0]'";
  }
  else {
    system "makeglossaries '$_[0]'";
  };
}

push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
$clean_ext = ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
```

Comment: I figure out to generate `synctex.gz` by changing the line into `$lualatex = "lualatex %O -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -file-line-error %S";` Cleaning is still not processed.

Comment: What didn't happen that you were expecting?  Setting `$cleanup_mode` as you do causes a cleanup followed by a compilation.  (The documentation implies that the compilation doesn't happen, which is incorrect.)

Comment: @JohnCollins Thanks for your feedback! I was hoping to clean all the extensions produced by compilation. `blg, aux, bbl` are still present before compilation starts. Even if I change to `$clean_ext = " %R.blg %R.aux %R.bbl";` or to `$clean_ext = " blg aux bbl";`

Comment: Basically I want, when a compilation starts to have only these files: `main.tex, main.pdf, main.synctex.gz`

Comment: I've checked: all the `blg, aux, bbl` files do get deleted in a clean up. However: (a) Just before the compilation, latexmk creates simple `aux` and `fdb_latexmk` files, to save a run of *latex on simple documents.  (b) The deletion of the `bbl` file is conditional -- see the latexmk documentation for details. You can have unconditional deletion of the `bbl` file by setting `$bibtex_use = 2;`. How do you know the `blg` and `bbl` files didn't get deleted in the clean up? What are their names?  (Some packages use `bbl` file(s) beyond the one with the standard name.)

Comment: `Just before the compilation, latexmk creates simple aux (...)` I just look at the directory and the file are not gone. Indeed, from 31KB is reset to zero, maybe this is what I don't understand. Possibly delete means, deleting content. The `aux` name is `main.aux` and my `.tex` file is `main.tex`

Comment: It was actually the `bbl` file(s) I was asking about.  Delete definitely means delete the file.  For the `aux` file there's a deletion followed by writing a new `aux`file of length 32 bytes, or probably 34 on Windows. The deletion and writing of the `aux` file happen very rapidly. Unless you do some tricks to cause delays of a few seconds, it would be hard to see the sequence of file deletion and creation.

Comment: All my auxiliary files are `main.*` as my primary `main.tex` file. See here: https://ibb.co/1LqVLP9

Comment: Ignore what I wrote.  I tried **exactly** your latexmkrc, and saw the problem.  Try adding the line `$cleanup_fdb = 1;` to your latexmkrc file.  It should solve the problem.  If you can confirm that, I'll turn this into an answer, with explanation. (And I'll need to improve the documentation!)

Comment: @JohnCollins I'm not so sure. I made a `.gif` and uploaded to my server because it is large. You can see it here: https://www.danilevici.ro/latexmk.gif

Comment: I think we may be talking at cross purposes as to what you wanted to achieve by setting `$cleanup_mode = 2;`.  The basic issue is what do you actually want a run of latexmk to achieve:  (a) Compilation followed by deletion of aux files?  Then running `latexmk` followed by `latexmk -c` is normally best. (b) Deletion of aux files followed by compilation? (c) Compilation both preceded and followed by deletion? (d) Just deletion of aux files? Then `latexmk -c` is best.

Comment: I was interested in `b` because (I don't know if it is the case with latexmk) in TexStudio when I made some mistakes I had to delete all aux files in order to obtain a compilation without error.

Comment: Then the results of the run you showed in the link are exactly what you wanted. Aux files were all deleted, and a full round of compilations done. At the end all the aux files remain present and they are all correct new versions.  (However, I find that it is rare that I need to delete aux files to overcome an error. So I would not use the latexmrc configuration to force that, but just run `latexmk -c` from the command line.)